# How to count number of words in a text string from user input

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starting to learn Dart and Flutter and have problem with one app. I'm trying to write an app that counts the number of words in a text string that a user enters. I wrote the countWords function for this, but I don't understand how to properly send a text string to this function.
Can someone please explain to me how to do this and correct my code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}

class MyFormState extends State {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 final myController = TextEditingController();
 int words_num = 0;
 void countWords() {
   var regExp = new RegExp(r"\w+(\'\w+)?");
   int wordscount = regExp.allMatches(myController.text); //here I have trouble
   setState(() {
     words_num = wordscount;
   });
 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: new Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'Text string:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your text string'),
              controller: myController,
            ),
            new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                countWords();
              },
              child: Text('Count words'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            new Text(
              'Number of words: $words_num',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ],
        )));
 }
}

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Count words app')),
    body: new MyForm())));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're assigning an `Iterable` to an `int`. Since you want the length, use the `length` property of the [`Iterable` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/length.html).

```
int wordscount = regExp.allMatches(myController.text).length;
```

This is assuming your regex is working and it appears to me that it is. If it's not then you can try this:

```
[\w-]+
```